# Getting .jar file onto a mobile phone error

Tags: java, java-me, jar, executable-jar, midp

I am trying to get a .jar file onto my mobile device. I have written a j2me application and I want to get it onto my phone. I have developed it in eclipse galileo and I export my project folder to a jar.

When I try to download the jar file from the internet onto my phone I get an "incorrect description" error.

Does anyone know how to get a j2me application onto a mobile device or why I may be getting this error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nine other questions in four months and *not one of them* has had an asnwer that was acceptable? (http://stackoverflow.com/faq) Just about the first one I looked at has a correct answer that should be accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java/2042829#2042829

Answer (score 2):

Your toolchain is supposed to generate both a .JAR file and a .JAD file.

As per the J2ME specifications, phones don't always have to allow the installation of the .JAR file.

You should deploy the .JAD file instead and make sure the .JAR is in an accessible location (handset storage or mobile network).

The .JAD file is supposed to contain the location of the .JAR file so the handset MIDlet installer can retrieve it.

EDIT:

There are a number of reasons why a phone would refuse to install a .JAD file.

It could be just plain wrong and not compliant with the MIDP specifications.
It could be signed by a certificate the phone doesn't like
It could use the wrong version of the J2ME configuration or profile.
It could contain permissions that the phone doesn't recognize
...

The best way to have your question answered would be to add the content of the .JAD file, the content of the manifest file packaged inside the .JAR file and the brand and model name of the handset you are trying to install your application on.

Comment: Eclipse generates the .jar file. I can get the associated .jad file created but I can't get either of them on my phone. I just get an incorrect description error when I try to install both on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using KToolbar the Samsung J2ME developer tool to generate the jar.

The Samsung SDK is simple and easy to generate your J2ME jars.

http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=3&cntsId=7985&listReturnUrl=http%3A%2F%2Finnovator.samsungmobile.com%3A80%2Fplatform.main.do%3FplatformId%3D3%26cateId%3D3%26cntsId%3D%26imgType%3D%26searchText%3Dsdk%26sortType%3D0%26codeType%3DC531%26nacode%3D%26indexDirection%3D1%26indexType%3D1%26listLines%3D10%26tabNum%3D1&linkType=0&nacode=&codeType=C531#