# Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: StaticMethod::$a

Tags: php

```
class StaticMethod
{

public $a=10;

public $b=20;

    public static function sum(){
        return (self::$a+self::$b);
    }
}

echo StaticMethod::sum();
```

Comment: You declared `$a` without `static`. What do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared your `sum` method as static, but you didn't declare your variables `$a` and `$b` as static.

```
class StaticMethod
{
    public static $a = 10;
    public static $b = 20;

    public static function sum() {
        return (self::$a + self::$b);
    }
}

echo StaticMethod::sum(); //returns 30
```

Comment: what if i want those variable as it is i.e not static. But want to access them in the function sum

Comment: You cannot access non-static properties from a static method. See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15118512/864233 - for more details on that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solved my problem. :-)