# Why can't we access private methods of inner class from the enclosing class?

Tags: java, oop, private

```
public class EnclosingClass{


    public void enclosingClassMethod(){
          InnerClass iC = new InnerClass();
          ic.innerClassPrivateMethod();   // this one works but why the following line doesn't       //work

          InnerClass.innerClassPrivateMethod();  // Why I can't call the method like this?


    }



    public class InnerClass{
         private void innerClassPrivateMethod(){

         }

    }

}
```

Why we can't call the `innerClassPrivateMethod()` like `InnerClass.innerClassPrivateMethod()`? I see "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method `innerClassPrivateMethod()` from the type EnclosingClass"

If I change both the `innerClassPrivateMethod` and `enclosingClassMethod` as private I get error for

```
 InnerClass iC = new InnerClass();
```

as "No enclosing instance of type Basics6 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type enclosingClass."

Comment: To answer the title question: you definitely can. What error does your code throw? Have you looked it up?

Comment: because it isn't static. You need an object to access it.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to call it statically when its not static

Comment: `I am not getting any error.` Then obviously there is no issue...Please be clear in what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, I am getting Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method innerClassPrivateMethod() error. But here everything is non-static, right? I haven't used static keyword

Comment: Please take that error message and put it into SO's search tool.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis  Apart from that error I am also facing the new issue, where if I change methods to private, I get the following error.  No enclosing instance of type Basics6 is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type enclosingClass.

Comment: Ok, now take that error message and put it into SO's search tool.

Comment: The `innerClassPrivateMethod` is an instance method, so it is not applicable to the class itself. That is why you can't call it from the `InnerClass` type directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling non-static method in static method in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to call the method of inner class using class name or we can say statically then you  need to do following changes.

1. Declare inner class method to be static.
2. A non static inner class can never have a static method So you need to change inner class to be static.

   public class EnclosingClass{

   ```
   public void enclosingClassMethod(){
         InnerClass iC = new InnerClass();
         iC.innerClassPrivateMethod();   // this one works but why the following line doesn't       //work

         InnerClass.innerClassPrivateMethod();  // This also works...


   }



   public static class InnerClass{     //  Class converted to static 
        private static void innerClassPrivateMethod(){   // Method converted to static

        }

   }
   ```

   }

Comment: Well explained. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the method is not denoted `static`, it is an instance method. In this case the instance must be the inner class. Since you don't access the method through an instance in the second call, there is no `this` reference, etc.

Defining `static` methods in an inner class is quite useless. First of all is the "supporting class" of a static method arbitrary. I might add a `public static void sort (int[] data);` as well to a `Utils` class as to a `ThisIsAUselessClass`. The only reason why it matters is because you sometimes want to make such methods `private`. Now since a class can see all (inclusing `private`) members of its inner classes and inner classes have access to all the private methods of its "outer class", there is no reason to define a static method in an inner class.