# Calling non-static method from another non-static method

Tags: java, non-static

Given `myClass` below and the non-static method `run()`, the following line of code is valid:

```
new myClass().move();
```

However, this is also valid:

```
move();
```

I understand the first attempt (`new myClass().move()`) creates an instance of the class and then calls the method on it. Does the second attempt also do the same thing but implicitly? In other words, are the 2 attempts really the same? If not, what is the fundamental difference and which one is preferred?

It seems OscarRyz's comment in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java/2042872#2042872) touched on this but he did not elaborate.

```
class myClass 
{
    void move() {
        //...some code
    }
    void run() {
        new myClass().move();
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Non-static methods _belong_ to an instance of the object (investigate "this" to learn more).  Carefully consider which instance the method would consider to be "this" in your code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not do the same thing.

With the first attemp `new myClass().move();` you create another instance of your class and then call the method on this new instance.

But in your second attempt `move();` you just call the method of your current instance. you already have initialized it. It's the same as `this.move();`

The second one is preferred, because you don't create another instance of your class but use the current one.

Comment: Thanks for also touching on the "preferred" method although what is preferred probably depends on the specific context. In the context of my code, I agree `this.move()` seems more efficient.

Comment: @sedeh Sure it depends on the context but most of time if you can access the method in the current instance it's preferred than create a new instance of the class.

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same.

If you call `move();`, you execute the method on the current instance of `myClass` (this is the same as `this.move();`).

If you call `new myClass().move();`, you execute it on a new instance of `myClass`.