# Which method is looked first by Compiler , Static or instance method when ClassName.method() is used?

Tags: java, static, compiler-errors

I want to get proper understanding why below compilation error?
As per my understanding If i use Test.xyz() then compiler look for only static method not for instance method then why below compilation fail?

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Test.xyz(10);     // compilation fail
    }   

    public void xyz(int i) {
    }
    public static void xyz(Integer i) {
    }   
 }
```

Every one please suggest why compilation fail rather than other suggestions and how to use , **I know all basic thing Autoboxing etc .**

Comment: `public static xyz(Integer i)` has no return type.

Comment: @Aditya Thanks I have edited void in static xyz function

Comment: Everyone please remove answer which said that static xyz method missed return type.

Comment: Ok. I removed all basic stuff ;). See the explanation in my answer...

Comment: @KamleshKanazariya I seriously doubt your understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why there is a compilation error

Compilation proceeds through different steps. Extracted from the JLS, following are the rules that explain why you got this error.

I skip the [first step](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.1) which is not relevant in your case. Everything happens in the same class.

Second step: [Determine method signature](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2)

> There may be more than one such method, in which case the most specific one is chosen. The descriptor (signature plus return type) of the most specific method is one used at run time to perform the method dispatch
>
> The first phase (§15.12.2.2) performs overload resolution **without permitting boxing or unboxing conversion**, or the use of variable arity method invocation. If no applicable method is found during this phase then processing continues to the second phase.

From above comments, the method you invoke with `Test.xyz(10);` is the one that takes an `int` parameter:

```
public void xyz(int i) {}
```

But now, there is a third step: [Choosing the appropriate method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.3)

> If the method invocation has, before the left parenthesis, a MethodName of the form **TypeName . Identifier**, or if the method invocation, before the left parenthesis, has the form TypeName . NonWildTypeArguments Identifier, then the **compile-time declaration must be static**, or a compile-time error occurs.

Again, from the above comment, you invoke the method in a `static` form,

```
Test.xyz(10);
```

but unfortunately, the method chosen from the second step, is **not** static.

It's why an IDE like Eclipse will suggest to "Change 'xyz()' to static".

But as explained in my first answer (deleted), you can either call `public void xyz(int i) {}` on an instance of class `Test`, or call the `static` method with an `Integer` parameter: `Test.xyz(Integer.valueOf(10));`.

Both will work.

Comment: Please check my edited question and edit your answer or remove answer for correctness because it is basic thing what you have given which i know already.

Answer (score 1):

You have no return type here:

```
public static xyz(Integer i) {
}
```

This should be void, if there is nothing to return:

```
public static void xyz(Integer i) {
}
```

And also, you need to make the first method static too:

```
public static void xyz(int i) {
}
```

So it can be called out of the static main method. It is not possible to call non-static methods out of static methods. More detailed explanation on this: [calling non-static method in static method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java)

Comment: Yes for the return type `void`. No for the need to have both method `static`. Even if the use case is a bit stretch and kind of not a good practice: same method name with native int and wrapper Integer parameters...

Comment: @flogy please Can you remove your answer because two many unwanted answer given when i forgot to put return type in question ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did the static class.

```
public class test {
       public static void main(String arg[]) {
        xyz(10);    
        }     

        public static void xyz(int i) {
        }   
    }
```

Comment: If you are not using static create an object of the class. Then refer `Test.xyz(10);` as in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So here comes the concept of `autoboxing` in Java.

U wrote:

```
Test.xyz(10); // Here 10 is a primitive int and not a java.lang.Integer object.
```

But since you are invoking the `xyz` method directly via class name, clearly means you want to access the `public static xyz(Integer)` method of the class `Test`.

But what happens in the compilation process is, first your `javac` compiler checks for method signature that is to be accessed, and after that, it checks for it's access(`public`, `private`, `protected`, `default`) and non-access(`final`, `static`, `etc`) modifiers.

The same thing happened with this code.

The first thing Java did was, it checked for the existence of the method with the signature `xyz(int)` and not `xyz(Integer)` coz you've passed in `10` and not `new Integer(10)` as a parameter.

It found two methods,
  1. `xyz(int)`
  2. `xyz(Integer)`

Had `xyz(int)` not existed, it would have applied the concept of autoboxing(ie, automatically convert `10` to `new Integer(10)`) and selected `xyz(Integer)` to be executed. But since `xyz(int)` exists, it does not autobox `10` to `new Integer(10)` and selects `xyz(int)` instead of `xyz(Integer)`.

Now since your compiler has selected `xyz(int)` to be executed, it checks for it's non-access modifiers. Now since the method `xyz(int)` is non-static, you are expected to access it with an object of `Test` class as follows:

```
new Test().xyz(10);
```

And still, if you want to access the `static xyz(Integer)` method, you may have to use:

```
Test.xyz(new Integer(10)); // You have to maunally autobox it.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Which method is looked first by Compiler , Static or instance method when ClassName.method() is used?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't even look at your `static` method. As it doesn't match the signature `xyz(int)`(`xyz(10)`). Your `static` method's signature is `xyz(Integer)`.