# Which method is looked first by Compiler , Static or instance method when ClassName.staticMethod() is used?

Tags: java, static, compiler-errors

I want to get proper understanding why below compilation error?
As per my understanding If i use Test.xyz() then compiler look for only static method not for instance method then why below compilation fail?

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Test.xyz(10);     // compilation fail
    }   

    public void xyz(int i) {
    }
    public static void xyz(Integer i) {
    }   
 }
```

Every one please suggest why compilation fail rather than other suggestions and how to use , **I know all basic thing Autoboxing etc .**

This question is asked already by me [Which method is looked first by Compiler , Static or instance method when ClassName.method() is used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29315688/which-method-is-looked-first-by-compiler-static-or-instance-method-when-classn?noredirect=1#comment46825092_29315688) but in that question most of people go in wrong direction due to mistake in my question so i moved that question to new question.

Comment: Is this the good process? why ask again the same question? delete the first question if you want to reformulate and start again.

Comment: You got the correct answer already, when you asked previously.  It makes no sense  to ask the same question again, in the hope of something different.

Comment: @DavidWallace I can't get proper understanding from previous question and all person go to wrong direction due to mistake in my previous question

Comment: Well, the correct answer is there, in the previous question.  Please don't fill up Stack Overflow with repeats of the same question.

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong in your assumption: the compiler will first look for most specific candidate methods with the **signature** (method name+parameters), without boxing. It means that the selected method is the non static one.

Then in a second step the compiler will see that you call the method as a `static` one with the syntax `<Class>.<method>()`.

It's why you get an error.