# Static and NonStatic

Tags: java, static, non-static

In editContact on the "[Contact.getName()]" I get the errors:

- Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getName() from the type 
   Contact
- Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to int

Why is this and how can I resolve the issue? thanks!

```
  public class ContactList
{
private final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONTACTS = 100;
private Contact[] contactList = new Contact[MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONTACTS];

public void addContact(String contactName, String contactNumber,
        String contactEmail, String contactAddress)
{
    if (Contact.getContactCount() >= MAX_NUMBER_OF_CONTACTS)
    {
        System.err
                .println("Eror: You have too many contacts, delete one of them you fool!");
        return;

public int editContact(String contactToEdit)
{
    if (editContact(contactToEdit) < 0)

    {
        return -1;
    }       

    else 
        contactList[Contact.getName()].setName("");
        contactList[Contact.getPhoneNumber()].setPhoneNumber("");
        contactList[Contact.getEmail()].setEmail("");
        contactList[Contact.getAddress()].setAddress("");

}
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java?rq=1) and check google for one of the many tutorials on what static means in java.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
contactList[Contact.getName()]
```

You're trying to use a `String` to access to an index of an array. Array are `int` index based.

Looks like you need to search for the `Contact` instance to update in your array. You can do this by using a `for` loop:

```
int index = 0;
for (Contact contact : contactList) {
    //use this or another condition
    if (contact.getName().equals(contactToEdit)) {
        //update this instance of contact
        contact.setName(...);
        return index;
    }
    index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you are trying to clear the contact details of `contactToEdit`

```
int contactIdToEdit = findContactIdForName(contactToEdit);
if (contactIdToEdit < 0)
    return;
Contact c = contactList[contactIdToEdit];
c.setName("");
c.setPhoneNumber("");
c.setEmail("");
c.setAddress("");
```

Comment: `contactToEdit` is a `String`.