# Static class and Session variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables, static-classes

I have defined a static class. In that static class I have the following method.

```
public static int GetUserId()
{
    if(IsUserLoggedIn())
    {
        return Convert.ToInt16(HttpContext.Current.Session["user"]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My question is this: When that function run for each user, will each user get a different value? (considering each user session gets different userId for the Session["user"].

I don't know if a static class is useful for this or can cause conflict issues. I am developing in C#/ASP.NET.

Comment: Yes it would get different values if all session has set different values. There is nothing to do with the static implementation of `GetUserId` method.

Comment: Q: I'm curious - does the code compile?

Comment: @paulsm4 What makes you think would cause the compilation error?

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Even when I read about static classes I had problem fully understanding it's limitations. thanks for clarifying this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, I believe the answer is yes, however you should avoid having hard-coded dependencies in non-factory methods... Consider accepting a `HttpSessionState` or at the very least a `HttpContext` object to act on, like so:

```
public static int GetUserId(HttpContext context)
{
    if(IsUserLoggedIn())
    {
        return Convert.ToInt16(context.Session["user"]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You should, however, likely be using the built in `IPrincipal` (`User`) property on the `HttpContext`, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

HttpContext will be different for every request so yes.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a error(calling non-static method from static method.). Please refer this :-

[calling non-static method in static method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java)

Comment: I don't see any such calls (HttpContext.Current is static) and the question is about C# not Java.