# How to access non-static method from within a static method?

Tags: php

I have two methods in a class, one of which is static. I want to access the non-static method from within the static method. Is that possible? I tried this:

```
class Foo {
   public function qux(){

   }
   public static function waldo(){
       self::qux(); // Non-static method Foo::qux() should not be called statically
   }
}
```

Is making qux a static method the only way to achieve this? What if the user doesn't want `qux()` to be a static method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling non-static method in static method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work as you need:

```
class Foo {
   public function qux(){

   }

   public static function waldo(){
       $foo = new Foo();
       $foo->qux();
   }
}
```

**There is no other way to call a dynamic method/function without creating the object itself first.**

Of course, if you will use the object only one-time and call all methods or functions immediately, you could use something like this:

```
class Foo {
   public function qux(){

   }

   public static function waldo(){
       (new Foo())->qux();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo {

   public function qux(){

   }

   public static function waldo(){
       $obj = new Static();
       $obj->qux();

   }
}
```