# How to declare global variables which doesn't change the value

Tags: android, function, initialization, global-variables

I have a function in whitch I use a global variable, and in this function I update this variable. I want to not update the value of this varible outside of this function.

```
public static int a = 0; //is global 
public static int b = 0;

 public void func(){
  if(a>c){
    a=a+b;
     }
 }
```

This function is called at 100ms

```
         final Handler handler = new Handler();
          Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            func();
               handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
           }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
```

Why "a" is initalized with zero everytime?

I want to do something like this:

```
 public void func(){
  int a=0;
  int b=0;
  while(a>c){
    a=a+b;
     }
 }
```

But I cannot to use while, because "c" is computed in another function, and if I use while, the value of "c" is not changed...

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make function static. Static variables are changed by static functions.

Comment: It is not possible, because in this function I call sent() function, that transmit messages via bluetooth. If I make "func()" static, I need to make send() static, which is not possible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java

Comment: My send() function is in the same class with func(). I will make a instance of current class?

Comment: I think you have to separate them in some way. Otherwise, i think a will start always with 0.