# Android Recycler View problem in "onBindViewHolder" function "static method cannot be called from non-static method"

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, static, non-static

I am new to android and java. I am not able to call `ViewHolder.setCategoryName(name);` in the `onBindViewHolder` function. I know there are probably similar questions but nothing has worked for me yet. The compiler gives error "non-static functions cannot be called from a static context", I haven't used static keyword anywhere in my code.

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList;

    public CategoryAdapter(List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList) {
        this.categoryModelList = categoryModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_item,viewGroup,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public  void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String icon = categoryModelList.get(position).getCategoryIconLink();
        String name = categoryModelList.get(position).getCategoryName();
        ViewHolder.setCategoryName(name);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryModelList.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

       private ImageView categoryIcon;
       private TextView categoryName;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)  {
              super(itemView);
              categoryIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);
              categoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);

        }

        private void setCategoryIcon(){

        }
        private void setCategoryName(String name){

            categoryName.setText(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `holder.setCategoryName(...)` instead of `ViewHolder.setCategoryName(name);` BTW Class name followed by  `.` followed by method name is interpreted as calling a static method in  Java

Comment: try with 
public void setCategoryName(String name){
            categoryName.setText(name);
        }

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calling non-static method in static method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList;

    public CategoryAdapter(List<CategoryModel> categoryModelList) {
        this.categoryModelList = categoryModelList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_item,viewGroup,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public  void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.bind(categoryModelList.get(position))

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return categoryModelList.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends  RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

       private ImageView categoryIcon;
       private TextView categoryName;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)  {
              super(itemView);
              categoryIcon = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);
              categoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_name);

        }

       public void bind(CategoryModel categoryModel){

             categoryName.setText(categoryModel.getCategoryName());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me alot thank you people! This community is awsome!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your method isn't static but you are trying to call from a static context:

```
 private void setCategoryName
```

You would need to do:

```
 private static void setCategoryName
```

However, for this type of action, you can just use the holder variable:

```
holder.bind(categoryModelList.get(position))
```