# Calling non static from static function Java

Tags: java, static-methods

Is it possible to call `disp()` method from `Test` Class ?

```
Class Test{
   Public static void main(String[] X){
    System.out.println(disp());
   }

   int disp(){
    return 10;
   }
}
```

Is the above code correct or not? if yes what will be the output?
I am very new to java.

Comment: no you can't call non static method from static method. this will help [Calling Non-Static Method In Static Method In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042813/calling-non-static-method-in-static-method-in-java)

Comment: can you share the correct piece of code

Comment: just add the `static` before `int` like this `static int disp(){}` it will work